# why is this "decryption" function not working in this javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops

I'm creating a website using HTML, CSS and Javascript. My home page consists of a header and 4 nav links to the other pages (Home, About, Portfolio, Contact). I want to achieve the effect of when the user loads the home page all the text is switching from cipher to cipher before "decrypting" character by character to the correct original text. For example a header with original plain text "My Website" would display 35 different ciphers of the same length before decrypting character by character after the last cipher is displayed: bdhyfiendk -> Mhdvrufgne -> Myhdbnfehs -> My hsnrifm -> My Whsnfje -> My Wehsbeq ... You get the idea. In my HTML code I have separated each text so header is class = ".header-text" and then the 4 nav elements follow the syntax class =".nav-".

The code I have written so far does the cipher bit correctly (so it displays all the different cipher texts) but then gets stuck on the last one and doesn't go ahead with the decryption. Here's the js file:

```
// Function to generate random foreign symbols
function generateRandomSymbols(length) {
// Define a string of symbols to choose from
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':\",.<>/?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
let result = '';

// Generate a random string of symbols with the specified length
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length);
    result += symbols.charAt(randomIndex);
}

return result;
}

// Function to decrypt the text
function decryptHeader(textElement, originalText, decryptionSpeed) {
let currentIndex = 0;

// Function to update the text character by character
function updateText() {
    if (currentIndex < originalText.length) {
        const charIndex = currentIndex;
        const char = originalText.charAt(charIndex);
        
        // Create a new text string with one character replaced
        const newText = textElement.textContent.substring(0, charIndex) + char + textElement.textContent.substring(charIndex + 1);
        
        // Update the text with the new string
        textElement.textContent = newText;
        currentIndex++;
        
        // Schedule the next character update with a delay
        setTimeout(updateText, decryptionSpeed); // Adjust the decryption speed
    }
}

// Start updating the text
updateText();
}

// Call the decryptText function for each element when the page loads
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Find the elements in the HTML using their classes
const headerElement = document.querySelector('.header-text');
const homeElement = document.querySelector('.nav-home');
const aboutElement = document.querySelector('.nav-about');
const portfolioElement = document.querySelector('.nav-portfolio');
const contactElement = document.querySelector('.nav-contact');

// Store the original texts
const originalHeaderText = headerElement.textContent;
const originalHomeText = homeElement.textContent;
const originalAboutText = aboutElement.textContent;
const originalPortfolioText = portfolioElement.textContent;
const originalContactText = contactElement.textContent;

// Set the decryption speed (time between character changes)
const decryptionSpeed = 100; // Adjust the decryption speed in milliseconds (e.g., 100 for 100ms)

// Generate an array of cipher texts with the same length as each original text
const cipherHeaderTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () => generateRandomSymbols(originalHeaderText.length));
const cipherHomeTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () => generateRandomSymbols(originalHomeText.length));
const cipherAboutTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () => generateRandomSymbols(originalAboutText.length));
const cipherPortfolioTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () => generateRandomSymbols(originalPortfolioText.length));
const cipherContactTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () => generateRandomSymbols(originalContactText.length));

// Function to update cipher text and start decryption for each element
function updateCipherText(element, cipherTexts) {
    let currentIndex = 0;

    function updateCipher(index) {
        if (index < cipherTexts.length) {
            element.textContent = cipherTexts[index];

            setTimeout(() => {
                updateCipher(index + 1);
            }, 50); // Adjust the cipher text change speed
        } else {
            // After displaying all cipher texts, start decrypting
            decryptText(element, originalText, decryptionSpeed);
        }
    }

    updateCipher(currentIndex);
}

// Start updating cipher text and decryption for each element
updateCipherText(headerElement, cipherHeaderTexts);
updateCipherText(homeElement, cipherHomeTexts);
updateCipherText(aboutElement, cipherAboutTexts);
updateCipherText(portfolioElement, cipherPortfolioTexts);
updateCipherText(contactElement, cipherContactTexts);
});
```

Comment: Also if there is a library I can use to generate more cryptic looking symbols id like to know and how to implement it as well:)

If you find there's a better more efficient way to write this code, do let me know, thanks!

Comment: i've personally never used it, but if you're looking for encrypting/decrypting things i've heard crypto.js is quite good

Comment: So the aim here is to achieve a decryption effect. Taking the header as an example, in the HTML the plaintext for the header is already stated as "My Website" and so the effect is that when the user loads the page the header cycles through multiple cryptographic cipher texts until it decrypts to the correct plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser's JavaScript console (typically e.g. F12 or cmd+shift+j), you can see the errors in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: decryptText is not defined

If you look in your code, you'll see that in your `else` block, you call the `decryptText` function, but further up, the function you're trying to call is actually named `decryptHeader`.

We can rename it, but if we do that, we then run into another problem:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: originalText is not defined

Once again, if you look at where you call `decryptText`, you can see that we try to pass in `originalText`, but that variable doesn't exist anymore: instead, we have 5 different variables.

At this point, we could fix it by just passing through the original text as one of the arguments of `updateCipherText`.

---

This works, but upon reaching this point, I noticed that essentially all of your code is now structured to be able to dynamically take in any element and apply the effect to it (which is good!), except for the part that sets it up: we have five lines to find the initial elements, five lines to get their text, five lines to call `updateCipherText`, etc. It's a lot of code, and a lot of repetition if you want to add another cyphered element in the future.

So, instead of finding each element by its class, you could probably invert that pattern, so that all elements you want to apply this effect to just get a `cypher` class in HTML, and then in JS you just find everything with the `cypher` class and apply the effect to all of those elements.

---

Here's a working version of your code with all the changes above applied:

```js
// Function to generate random foreign symbols
function generateRandomSymbols(length) {
  // Define a string of symbols to choose from
  const symbols =
    "!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}|;':\",.<>/?abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  let result = "";

  // Generate a random string of symbols with the specified length
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length);
    result += symbols.charAt(randomIndex);
  }

  return result;
}

// Function to decrypt the text
function decryptText(textElement, originalText, decryptionSpeed) {
  let currentIndex = 0;

  // Function to update the text character by character
  function updateText() {
    if (currentIndex < originalText.length) {
      const charIndex = currentIndex;
      const char = originalText.charAt(charIndex);

      // Create a new text string with one character replaced
      const newText =
        textElement.textContent.substring(0, charIndex) +
        char +
        textElement.textContent.substring(charIndex + 1);

      // Update the text with the new string
      textElement.textContent = newText;
      currentIndex++;

      // Schedule the next character update with a delay
      setTimeout(updateText, decryptionSpeed); // Adjust the decryption speed
    }
  }

  // Start updating the text
  updateText();
}

// Set the decryption speed (time between character changes)
const decryptionSpeed = 100;

// Call the decryptText function for each element when the page loads
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Find the elements in the HTML using their classes
  const elementsToCypher = document.querySelectorAll(".cypher");

  for (const element of elementsToCypher) {
    const originalText = element.textContent;
    updateCipherText(element, originalText);
  }
});

function updateCipherText(element, originalText) {
  const cipherTexts = Array.from({ length: 35 }, () =>
    generateRandomSymbols(originalText.length)
  );

  let currentIndex = 0;

  function updateCipher(index) {
    if (index < cipherTexts.length) {
      element.textContent = cipherTexts[index];

      setTimeout(() => {
        updateCipher(index + 1);
      }, 50); // Adjust the cipher text change speed
    } else {
      // After displaying all cipher texts, start decrypting
      decryptText(element, originalText, decryptionSpeed);
    }
  }

  updateCipher(currentIndex);
}
```

```html
<div class="cypher header-text">Header</div>
<div class="cypher nav-home">Home</div>
<div class="cypher nav-about">About</div>
<div class="cypher nav-portfolio">Portfolio</div>
<div class="cypher nav-contact">Contact</div>
```

---

To improve in the future, I'd recommend

- Making sure you know how to use your brower's JS console to find and debug errors
- Using an IDE like VSCode when writing your code, with language support plugins for JS. I highly recommend this, as it'll help you find these sorts of errors before you even run the code (e.g. it would highlight `decryptText` in red in the editor because it doesn't exist, etc).

I also think that the way we build the cyphers is a little weird, because we have multiple `setTimeout` calls (e.g. one for the first cyphers, one for the second stage). I think another improvement you could make would be to generate just one single array that contains all of the steps (including the 35 original cyphers, and then all of the subsequent steps), and then just have one setTimeout loop that goes through and applies them.

A few other code quality things, you should probably move your `symbols` and `decryptionSpeed` constants out of their functions and up to the top, so that they're together and it's easier to change them in the future. I'd also recommend renaming `decryptionSpeed` to e.g. `decryptionSpeedMs`, because having the unit in the name makes things so much more readable in other parts of the code that use the variable, even if you do have the comment next to it when it's defined.

I also think a lot of the comments are actually pretty redundant / not useful, and you might actually just be better off without them --- e.g.

```js
// Function to decrypt the text
function decryptText
```

This actually tells me nothing, right. In general, I actually think it's better to avoid comments if your variable and function names can just be very explicit and "self-documenting" instead.

Comment: Thank you this works! I need to use the debugging feature more I don't really know how to use it at the moment.
The function name mistake is a silly one I should've caught it, I initially had this code working fine for just taking the header element and then decided I wanted the effect for the other elements on the page too. This solution is much easier to read and I appreciate the coding tips!